# Create file image container

Tags: filesystems, dd

I would like to create a 100GB file to use as a file-system. The file will be stored on an encrypted volume, so the file/file-system itself does not need to be (further) encrypted. Searching has revealed many different methods of doing this. Some use `losetup`, some don't. Is the following an acceptable method?

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=~/theFile.img bs=1M count=10240
$ mkfs.ext4 ~/theFile.img   # will prompt about block special device
$ sudo mount -o loop ~/theFile.img /media/mountPoint
```

Comment: Besides this creating a 10GB File instead of 100GB, thanks alot, changing the count to 102400 fulfilled my needs :)

Comment: You may want to use `truncate -s 10240M ~/theFile.img` to just allocate the file size without writing zeros to it. Just saves you some time :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. BS and COUNT should be lowercase:

   `dd if=/dev/zero of=~/theFile.img bs=1M count=10240`
2. you need to make the /media/MountPoint directory if it doesn't already exist:

   `sudo mkdir -p /media/MountPoint`

Apart from those two things, what you have there should work.

It's usually better to be explicit than rely on implicit behaviour, so you might want to change the mount line to:

`sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop ~/theFile.img /media/mountPoint`

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. It was the `M` in `1M` that had to be uppercase. Don't know why I put `bs` and `count` in uppercase too. Thanks for the improved `mount`.

Comment: I've accepted a suggested edit to my question to correct the uppercase mistake and to explicitly specify a loop device in the `mount`.

Answer (score 6):

Except for the capital letters in the `dd` options and not including the `loop` option in `mount`, I find this perfectly valid. `mkfs` is warning you that is not using a block device to make sure that you know what you're doing.

Anyway, at the end, you will be using a loop device:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=~/theFile.img bs=1M count=10
$ /sbin/mkfs.ext4 theFile.img
$ sudo mount -o loop theFile.img /mnt/tmp/
$ df -h

/dev/loop0            9,7M  1,1M  8,1M  12% /mnt/tmp
```

Comment: The `-o loop` may or may not be required...depends on the version of mount.  My current version doesn't require it, but I remember having to specify it in the past.  Still, like i said - it's better to be explicit than implicit in scripts, serves as documentation of WTF Was I Thinking When I Did That?

Comment: Agreed. (Note: I'm using mount 2.17.2-9 from the current Debian Stable)